# Where in my configuration can I find my broker database and Tridion DB values?

Tags: broker, 5.3

I have two databases one normal Tridion and one for broker Database. I am using Tridion 5.3.

How does Tridion know which broker database to use? How do I put it in my configuration?

Answer (score 6):

in `cd_broker_conf.xml`

you have section like following.

```
<Storage>
      <Database Type="sql">
      <Pool Type="jdbc" Size="5" MonitorInterval="60" IdleTimeout="120" CheckoutTimeout="120" />
          <DataSource Class="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource">
          <Property Name="serverName" Value="db"/>
          <Property Name="portNumber" Value="1433"/>
          <Property Name="databaseName" Value="Tridion_broker"/>
          <Property Name="user" Value="uid"/>
          <Property Name="password" Value="pwd"/>
        </DataSource>
      </Database>
    </Storage>
```

Answer (score 3):

[As Raj says](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/2721/71), this is stored in the `cd_broker_conf.xml` file.

You will find this file in to following folder: `C:\Program Files\Tridion\config`  (assuming that Tridion was installed in the default location)

**NOTE:** If you make any changes to this file, you will need to restart the `Tridion Content Broker` and `Tridion Content Deployer` Windows Services (or the Java processes), to get the changes to take effect.

You may also need to restart the `Tridion Cache Channel Service` and `Tridion Dynamic Linking` Services for good measure too.

Comment: You will also need to restart the Deployer service (if installed) as that is also using the Broker for storing published content.

Comment: Indeed the linking service also used the Broker configuration ;)

Comment: Thanks for all of your answers Raj,Miguel,Jonathan and Bart :)

Comment: Actually, Bart , I am planning on refreshing my dev/test tridion  databases from live. I have two databases one tridion and one broker. So, I was wondering if I clean the broker database completely and recreate all tables and users for brokers, how would the broker tables then populate with values, I mean what would trigger that.

Comment: @neil if you want to clean the db, what is purpose of restoring it from production? Is publishing already working in your environment or you need to setup it?

Comment: @neil - I guess that this is from Step 10 (**(re)publish all content that you need again, or restore the Broker database and copy the content of your web server over.**) in Bart's excellent answer to your [SDL Tridion R5.3 : How to refresh one environment with data from another environment](http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/2484/) question.  Unless you have a massive amount of content, I would recommend re-publishing all content to an empty broker database.

Comment: Yea, we do have massive amount of data. We have three brokers for three different applications, I am trying to understand how does data move from the normal Tridion db to the broker ones. How does it know which broker to move to? and when does it do that. Could you please let me know

Comment: @neil You should check out Julian Wraith's [Basic Publishing Flow](http://www.julianwraith.com/2013/08/sdl-tridion-whiteboarding-basic-publishing-flow/) whiteboarding video.  This should help to clear up the relation ship between the Content Manager, publishing and the Broker Database.

Answer (score 3):

Just want to add that in case of a J2EE application the configuration in the cd_broker_conf.xml could be pointing to a JNDI instead having those values written in the configuration file. 
In that case you will have to go to the definition of the JNDI in the Application Server to find those values.

Comment: Yup thats right . It does point to jndi, I know the databases and passwords, I just need to know the above.